# Unstacking a grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a grouped pandas dataframe that is grouped by 3 layers: Date, City, Neighborhood, and then "Gaps".

The gaps column holds the values I am trying to unstack.

The bins in the gaps column include: 0, 0.5 - 3, 3.5 to 5, 5.5 to 7, etc.

I want to unstack the data so that with each neighborhood I can see the count for each gap.

Is it possible to unstack the gap values while preserving the groups of zone, city and date?

The end goal here is the have a bar graph per city at each point in time, where each bar shows the stacked gaps for a neighborhood.

When I try to use the function as unstack('gaps'), I get a key error that says 'Level gaps not found'

Here is the code that got me here:

```
minG = tFrame.groupby(['Date','City','Neighborhood','ID']) # there are multiple gap values for each ID

grouped_gap = minG['GAP'] # the series of gaps for each ID

groupedMin = grouped_gap.agg([('Minimum', 'min')]) # I need the minimum gap value for each ID

groupedMin = groupedMin.replace(-1, 0) # the datasource had -1 gap values

label = ['0', '0.5 to 3', '3 to 5', '5 to 7', '7 to 9', '9 to 12', '12+'] # sets the label for each desired bin

groupedMin['gaps'] = pd.cut(groupedMin['Minimum'], bins = [-1, 0.5, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 48], labels = label) # places each ID in a bucket, based on the labels
```

Any help to get from here to those bar graphs is appreciated.

Edit:

Here's what I'm seeing:

1. This first pic shows the column for Minimum, which is the minimum gap value for each vehicle
   http://i58.tinypic.com/2co2zja.jpg
2. This second pic shows the new column gaps, where each value of Minimum has been bucketed:
   http://i60.tinypic.com/1j47bm.jpg

Edit #2 with sample code and dataframe:

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

bFrame = DataFrame([["672,059,124","Central Business District","Baltimore","6/1/2013 13:00",4],
                   ["672,059,144","Central Business District","Baltimore","6/1/2013 13:00",1], 
                   ["673,928,993","Goucher/Towson (Baltimore County)","Baltimore","6/1/2013 13:00",-1],
                   ["647,380,667","Goucher/Towson (Baltimore County)","Baltimore","6/1/2013 13:00",4], 
                   ["801,833,082","Brookline","Boston","6/1/2013 13:00",22], 
                   ["801,833,082","Brookline","Boston","6/1/2013 13:00",24],
                   ["821,833,082","Brookline","Boston","6/1/2013 13:00",5],
                   ["956,264,933","Financial District","Boston","6/1/2013 13:00",-1],
                   ["956,264,933","Financial District","Boston","6/1/2013 13:00",2]],
                   columns=["ID","Neighborhood","City","Date","GAP"])
minGap = bFrame.groupby(['Date','City','Neighborhood','ID']) # there are multiple gap values for each ID

grouped_g = minGap['GAP'] # the series of gaps for each ID

groupedMini = grouped_g.agg([('Minimum', 'min')]) # I need the minimum gap value for each ID

groupedMini = groupedMini.replace(-1, 0) # the datasource had -1 gap values

lab = ['0', '0.5 to 3', '3 to 5', '5 to 7', '7 to 9', '9 to 12', '12+'] # sets the label for each desired bin

groupedMini['gaps'] = pd.cut(groupedMini['Minimum'], bins = [-1, 0.5, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 48], labels = lab) # places each ID in a bucket, based on the labels
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of what your dataframe looks like. Preferably after the `groupedMin['gaps'] =` line.

Comment: @freddygv you still don't have a sample dataframe. Also, you can copy in text (rather than images) of the dataframe, hightlight and ctrl+k to indent to code-format.

Comment: Hi sorry, I attached code with a smaller, sample frame. This gets you to where I am.